# adding noise to a column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395072/non-finite-value-supplied-in-ggstatsplot/65395399#65395399), I want to add some random noise to every value in a column in dplyr. However, when I tried the below code I get identical values back. I understand why this is happening (dplyr generate the random number and then uses that very same number to add to every single value). Is there any way to prevent this?

```
data <- data.frame(value=c(1,1,1,1,1)) %>% mutate(value = value + 1e-3*runif(1)) %>% print

# print(data)
#      value
# 1 1.000236
# 2 1.000236
# 3 1.000236
# 4 1.000236
# 5 1.000236
```

Comment: Ugh, just realized: I only need to add ` rowise() %>% ` and it generates a new random number every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer. Adding `rowwise()` evaluates each row individually and thus gives a new random number.

```
data <- data.frame(value=c(1,1,1,1,1)) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(value = value + 1e-3*runif(1)) %>% print

# print(data)
#      value
# 1 1.000625                
# 2 1.000764                
# 3 1.000588                
# 4 1.000536                
# 5 1.000079
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with [`jitter`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/jitter.html):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)    # Make the results reproducible
data <- data.frame(value=c(1,1,1,1,1)) %>% mutate(value = jitter(value))
data
#      value
#1 1.0058761
#2 0.9957690
#3 1.0047401
#4 0.9990756
#5 0.9854439
```

Answer (score 2):

You could generate your random vector externally and then add it to data$value:

```
nrows <- nrow(data)
rands <- 1e-3 * runif(nrows)
data$value <- data$value + rands
```

Stepwise clarity works better for me.